# Trying to register a product and requesting user confirmation using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, product, registration

I'm new in programming and I was trying to develop a code to Register a Product, but I don't know how to solve this part below:

Register a Product Program
The required fields are:

1. Name
2. Description
3. Quantity
4. Price
5. Manufacturer
6. Button (one) to submit the information;
7. Show information submitted by user - Confirm or Denied (Two) Buttons;

Below is my current code, if you can help me with these final steps of Submit data, Show data to User Confirm and Register, I appreciate it.

```
Hello World!
I´m new in programming and I was trying to develop a code to Register a Product, but I don´t know how to solve this part below:

Register a Product Program
The required fields are:
 1. Name
 2. Description
 3. Quantity
 4. Price
 5. Manufacturer
 
1. Button (one) to submit the information;
2. Show information submitted - User Confirm/Denied Buttons (Two);

Below is my current code, if you can help me with these final steps of Submit data, Appear data to Confirm and Register, I appreciate it.


function showInput() {
      document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("nameid").value;
      document.getElementById('show2').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("aboutid").value;
      document.getElementById('show3').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("quantityid").value;
      document.getElementById('show4').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("priceid").value;
      document.getElementById('show5').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("manufacturerid").value;
    }
    function showResults() {
      var showall = ("show1" < br > "show2" < br > "show3" < br > "show4" < br > "show5" < br > );
    }
    <form id="ProductRegistration" method="get">
      <label for="name">Product Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="nameid"> <br>
      <label for="about">Product Description: </label>
      <input type="text" name="about" id="aboutid"> <br>
      <label for="quantity">Product Quantity: </label>
      <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantityid"> <br>
      <label for="price">Product Price: </label>
      <input type="number" min="0.00" max="10000.00" step="0.01" name="price" id="priceid"> <br>
      <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer: </label>
      <input type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturerid"> <br>

      <input type="submit" onclick="showResults();" value="Submit"><br>
      <p style="text-align: center;">Is the data correct? If yes, click on Register. If not, please fill it in again.</p>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();" value="Register"><br>
<end>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the default javascript's confirm() function where you can show all the results of the input fields and take the user comfirmation accordingly, but for me this is not a fancy one.

You can read more about comfirm() function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

You can also use the sweet alert library for the same, read about it [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

And the way you are doing this is not correct.

Please look this stackoverflow's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017385/sweet-alert-confirmation-before-submit-form-using-ajax), that help you to achieve the goal.

I hope this helps.